# how to configure veto files on samba ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: file, samba

How to configuration veto files on ubuntu server to allow some file ex : test.exe, if veto files on samba is *.exe
i try :

```
veto files = *.exe
allowed file = !test.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

To forbid:

> veto files = /*.exe/
>
> delete veto files = yes